# IPC among multiple process using shared condition variable

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, shared-memory

I am trying to achieve **IPC** between two process (Process1 and Process2) using shared memory that too **without wasting cpu** while waiting for its turn. It's **basically use of condition variable in multiple process scenario**.

Although I am **able to do it in parent-child scenario,** but not able to do two separate process (process1 & process2) scenario.

***Here is what I have done in parent-child scenario.***

****Created mptr (shared mutex) and cvptr ( condition variable) using PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED flag,****

```
pthread_cond_t *cvptr;    //Condition Variable Pointer
pthread_condattr_t cattr; //Condition Variable Attribute
pthread_mutex_t    *mptr; //Mutex Pointer
pthread_mutexattr_t matr; //Mutex Attribute

int   shared_mem_id;      //shared memory Id
int   *mp_shared_mem_ptr; //shared memory ptr -- pointing to mutex
int   *cv_shared_mem_ptr; //shared memory ptr -- pointing to condition variable



   // Setup Mutex
rtn = pthread_mutexattr_init(&matr);
rtn = pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&matr,PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
rtn = pthread_mutex_init(mptr, &matr);


 //Setup Condition Variable
    rtn = pthread_condattr_init(&cattr);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&cattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED));
    pthread_cond_init(cvptr, &cattr);
```

send signal from parent process

```
sleep(2);
    pthread_cond_signal( cvptr ); // send signal to child process
```

and waiting for signal in child process.

```
pthread_cond_wait( cvptr, mptr );
```

**as per property of condition variable while child waiting for its turn , it is not wasting  any CPU cycle.**

---

> To make sure, parent must send signal only after child starts waiting
>   for signal, **sleep(2)** is added before  pthread_cond_signal( cvptr );

---

**While I am using same concept in two process scenario , process2 is not getting any signal from process1.**

Process2 is waiting infinitely. In seems signal is lost.

I first run process2, then run process1 to make sure process1 signal must be delivered only after when process2 starts waiting.

Where I am making mistake ?

I am using ubuntu12.04, and gcc.
Any help to achieve the same will highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Note :** I am able to do IPC among multiple process using simple shared memory concept, where initially shared_variable value =0 and process1 makes it to 1 to notify process2 to starts its work and after that process2 changes the shared_variable =0 and this continues. This solution actually waste cpu while waiting for updated value of shared variable to continue its working. like `while (shared_stuff->written_by_you == 1) {do nothing;}`

Answer (score 1):

As it's not obvious from the code you show let me state this:

You ought to place the mutex and the condition variable inside the shared memory, to make them available to anybody via the shared memory. Placing a pointer to them in shared memory is not enough.

Comment: "Placing a pointer to them in shared memory is not enough", most likely not even valid as the processes have different address spaces.